# How to have an Coroutine Act like an Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have been told I should not be using Updates when I don't need to use them.  I am not sure when to not use them, but I am trying to figure it out.

I want to have an event, "Wave", run for 20 seconds and then switch to a random "Wave" and run for another 20 seconds and keep repeating this cycle.

Game Manager:

```
void Start()
{
    StartFireWaves();
}

public void StartFireWaves()
{
    StartCoroutine(wm.SelectWave());
}
```

Wave Manager:

```
public IEnumerator SelectWave()
{

   float waitFor;
   float diff = 0;

    diff = nextWaveAT - Time.time;

    if (diff <= 0f)
    {
        SpawnFlames();
        waitFor = Random.Range(15, 20);

    }
    nextWaveAT = nextWaveAT + waitFor;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitFor);
}
```

SpawnFlames:

```
void SpawnFlames()
{
    float val = Random.value;

    if (val < .25f)
    {
        Wave1();
    }
    if (val >= .25f && val < .5f)
    {
        Wave2();
    }
    if (val >= .5f && val < .75f)
    {
        Wave3();
    }
    else
    {
        Wave4();
    }
}
```

I am assuming this is how it should work, but it doesn't seem to keep "updating" or running.  It just runs once and then nothing happens.

Comment: **I want to have an event (Wave) run for 20 seconds** What is (Wave)? **then switch to a different one.** What different one? You question does not provide enough detail get help. My answer provides a way to do something for 20 seconds or the amount of time provided then do another thing after it. Please rephrase your question and explain what you want to do in 20 seconds and what you want to do after that...

Comment: It needs to keep repeating the whole cycle over and over again  choose a WAVE (run for 20 seconds), Choose  WAVE (run for 20 seconds), etc...

Comment: Run Wave1 for 20 seconds, Wave2  for 20 seconds Wave3,Wave4 then repeat again? Loop forever?

Comment: No, Randomly selected (1 to 4) run 20 seconds; Randomly Select ( 1 - 4), run 20 seconds; Randomly select (1 - 4) run 20 seconds.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes no it does. Will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Coroutine` with multiple nested `while` loops to do this. The first `while` loop is to make it run forever until stopRunningWaves() function is called. The second `while` loop is used to run the wave for **x** amount of time then jumps back to the first `while` loop.

```
bool keepRunningWaves = false;
IEnumerator startingRunningWaves(float second = 20)
{
    if (keepRunningWaves)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    keepRunningWaves = true;

    while (keepRunningWaves)
    {

        float timer = 0;

        int randWave = Random.Range(1, 5);
        while (timer < second)
        {
            if (!keepRunningWaves)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            if (randWave == 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("Running Wave 1");
                Wave1();
            }
            else if (randWave == 2)
            {
                Debug.Log("Running Wave 2");
                Wave2();
            }
            else if (randWave == 3)
            {
                Debug.Log("Running Wave 3");
                Wave3();
            }
            else if (randWave == 4)
            {
                Debug.Log("Running Wave 4");
                Wave4();
            }

            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        //Reset Timer for next run 
        timer = 0;

        yield return null;
    }

   keepRunningWaves = false;
}

void stopRunningWaves()
{
    keepRunningWaves = false;
}
```

To test it, use **3** seconds to do it so that you will save your time:

```
StartCoroutine(startingRunningWaves(3));
```

Comment: If  each wave run for more than x seconds, that's because the last random number is the-same as the new/current random number. It is your responsibility to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  How does the stopRunningWaves get trigger to turn the keepRunningWaves false?

Comment: @TimCooley `stopRunningWaves()` is not called in my example above. You can use it when you want to **stop** moving the waves. I don't know when you want to stop moving the waves. Only you know that. You said you want to loop forever but I added it to let you stop the loop and exit the coroutine.

Comment: @TimCooley Just modified it to fix a bug. Copy the new code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That is all working.  Now I can see how it works!

Comment: Is a nested while loop inside a while loop a bad thing?

Comment: @TimCooley No. Sometimes, it is required to do stuff. You must put `yield return null;` inside the `while` loop so that it wont freeze unity.